# How would I send an ephemeral message in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I tried to do a bit of searching of my own, but I was unable to find anything. So I ask you guys, does anyone here know how to send an ephemeral message in discord.py?

this was what I was doing(I heard somewhere that this works, but it didnt):

```
await message.edit(content="Review  submission cancelled.", embed=None ,ephemeral=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only send an ephemeral message as a response to an interaction, eg. as a response to a button click or a slash command using
`interaction.response.send_message("Text", ephemeral=True)`

[Docs on interaction response](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.InteractionResponse)

You sadly can't send an ephemeral message if it's not responding to an interaction, and you also can't answer to the same interaction twice.

Comment: I'm using slash commands
But I don't get how I would get the interaction object though

Comment: You can respond to interactions twice by using defer() and then with multiple followup()

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little bit help but I hope my answer will help someone.
As LoahL already said, it is possible to send an ephemeral message with an object of **discord.Interaction** class.

Here as a code example:

```
@discord.app_commands.command(description="It is my_command")
async def my_command(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!", ephemeral=True)
```

As you may noticed I use the **discord.app_commands** module which passes a **discord.Interaction** to the command.

There is also one more way to create commands with **discord.py** - using **@bot.command()** or similar **@discord.ext.commands.command()**. Those decorators pass a **discord.ext.commands.Context** to function and the code will be something like:

```
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command(description="It is my_command")
async def my_command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!", ephemeral=True)
```

I am not sure about the second part of the code, but, according to [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) it has to work.