# Discord.py - Message, send empheral message (which only one person can see)

Tags: python, discord.py

can anyone please tell me how to use slash commands and empheral messages with any module in Python discord.
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGaFs.png

Thank you!

Comment: You can send ephemeral messages with `InteractionResponse.send_message(ephemeral=True)`. A library which supports both [ephemeral messages and slash commands](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord/blob/master/examples/application_commands/slash_basic.py) is [nextcord](https://github.com/nextcord/nextcord)

Answer (score 0):

```
interaction.response.send_message("Text", ephemeral=True)
```

Notice that this can only be done as answer to an interaction.

---

If you want to know more read [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074937/how-would-i-send-an-ephemeral-message-in-discord-py) that's almost a duplicate.