# How to send Ephemeral message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Before I continue, I have in fact read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074937/how-would-i-send-an-ephemeral-message-in-discord-py). It did not answer my question, or at least clarify exactly how to do it for slash commands that's why I'm doing a similar question.

How would you send a ephemeral/only user can see message? I'm using [slash commands](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) for my command.

Currently this is what I have.

```py
await ctx.send(f"{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms", ephemeral=True)
```

Here is the obviouse error.

```py
TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ephemeral'
```

Comment: The library you sent is not pip installing (at least for me), and their documentation seems to be contradicting their pypi page. Can you specify what type `ctx` is, and where the documentation for that would be?

Comment: i recommend you move to a proper fork-library of dpy such as disnake,  pycord, nextcord.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs The ```ctx``` is a SlashContext and I couldn't exactly find the documentation, sorry.

Comment: @Ares I will look into it.

Comment: @Ares You were right Pycord is the way to go. I'm switching over my library right now.

Comment: glad i could help

Comment: @Ares Why? From what I've seen discord.py is still maintained.

Comment: @5px at the time discord.py wasn't maintained. So I used pycord. However now discord.py is fully updated and maintained. Thank god. Although finding documentation for the updated discord.py leaves newer developers at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@bot.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Hello", ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: Works as of the **1.6.0 discord.py-rewrite**