# How do you send a private message in discord.py to command user?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, pycord

## Please reference to the image below:

[image: NQN bot sends an "only you can see this" message]

I know how to send a private message DM to user... But I want the bot to send a message in the CHANNEL instead, yet make the message content see-able only by the command user. How do you send a message that says: "only you can see this".

## Also, can this be done with embeds?

is it possible to send a private EMBED to user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I send an ephemeral message in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074937/how-would-i-send-an-ephemeral-message-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use like the above image then this is only possible in splash commands and buttons for now. But if you want to send user a embed in dm then you can and also you can also send this thing in embed.

If you want to use this in splash command you can do like this:

```py
interaction.response.send_message("Text", ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to remind you that these messages that only you can see can only be triggered with interactions, that means slash commands, buttons, drop down menus and other discord UI. Since discord.py does currently support this kind of stuff in its stable version 1.7.3 you can't do that unless you update to the unstable 2.0 or use pycord. But these only you can see msgs also only can be trigged where they were executed, since you cant slash command in a DM it is impossible to DM someone with only you can see this message. However since when u send a DM to the user only he gets dm anyway. If u want to use embeds just create a embed with the docs or a embed builder like https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/ and use it in e.x. ctx.respond(embed=embed). Hope that helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).