# How to make Only you can see this message in Discord py?

Tags: python, discord.py

**How to make Only you can see this message in Discord py ?**

i want to make discord bot reply user with 'only you can see this message' in discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(
    help_command=None,
    command_prefix=">"
)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connection as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.reply('Hello')

client.run('token')
```

Comment: Add `ephemeral=True` to your `send_message()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I send an ephemeral message in discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074937/how-would-i-send-an-ephemeral-message-in-discord-py)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this :

One simple solution is through sending DM (direct message) to the user, here is an example :

```
DM = await ctx.author.create_dm()
await DM.send("Hello")
```

The another solution, the more complicated one is through responding to interactions with ephemeral messages, which are related to slash-commands and buttons. I do not recommend doing it this way if you are not already dealing with interactions, since you will have to implement a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display this message then

```
@client.command()
async def Hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')
```